# 4 bytes increase by 1

Tags: arrays, vb.net, byte

I'm trying to increase 4 byte value by 1, for example i have 00000000 so after increment it will be 00000001, 00000002, 00000003, then when least significant byte will reach FF, byte next to it will start counting - "00000100, 00000101,  00000102, 00000103", then whe this byte reach FF byte next to it starts 00010000, 00010101,  00010102, 00010103" etc... the complete value is FFFFFFFF.

I can do it with c#, but with vb comes the problem

```
private void incrementAtIndex(byte[] array, int index) {
    if (array[index] == byte.MaxValue) {
        array[index] = 0;

        if (index > 0)
            incrementAtIndex(array, index - 1);
    }
    else {
        array[index]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice homework. But why don't you use a INT32 instead? Part of the purpose?

Comment: You mean put 4bytes into int32 var then increase this var? btw its not homework)

Comment: If you're trying to do this in VB.NET then showing us C# code is fairly useless. Where's the VB code you tried?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the problem is.